# Interpretation of horizon display

Tags: geology, geophysics, earthquakes, seismic

I am currently working on a project that involves using seismic attributes as input parameters in a neural network for estimation of porosity and permeability for a reservoir. Now, I need to correlate between well log and seismic data, so I need to learn how to interpret some special kind of images, such as this:

[image: Image of a seismic horizon]

Can someone tell me what can be interpreted from this image?

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer this without knowing a bit about what you think it is. I mean, it's a raster image showing the two-way time in ms to some continuous seismic reflection (probably) that someone thinks is important in this seismic volume. But the rest of your question makes it sound like you probably know that. Can you elaborate on your question?